# HtmlInputText does not contain a definition for InnerHtml

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written a code for textbox element in Sample.aspx file as follows:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server"/>
```

This auto-generated the code in Sample.aspx.designer.cs

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText Text1;
```

Then to populate it's html from code-behind I have written this code:

```
Text1.InnerHtml = "Sample text";
```

This is giving me an error

> HtmlInputText does not contain a definition for InnerHtml

What is the problem. Why it's giving me an error?

Comment: Ok. Finally I found the problem and solution. This was due to copy-paste habit.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9600186/1789796

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.Value` property to programmatically determine the text entered by the user into the text box. You can also use this property to provide default text for the text box.

```
Text1.Value = "Sample text";
```

Comment: Change it to value

Comment: Hi @SushantTayade if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the asp.net TextBox Control? You have more options that way

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

Text1.Text = "Sample text";
```

Comment: This is working. But why simple <input> is not working. I have used in other pages, same like I have posted and it is not showing any errors over there.

Comment: I think you are confusing it with  a `<div runat="Server">`. That has a `InnerHtml` property. An `input` does not.

Comment: I have used same code for accessing input values from my login.aspx page. Is it the thing that I can use it for accessing but not for populating?

Answer (score 0):

`.Value` should work. Please check if there are any placeholder issue in your page. You can see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148161/set-html-input-textboxs-display-text-using-c-sharp) for the similar type problem. In the link there are also an alternative way to set value into the input using JQuery/Javascript.